# Responsive web design - add correct media queries

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, responsive

I developed a website with wordpress and its design is fine for desktop and tablet, but when it comes the phone's visualization I have problems in setting a good design.
I am trying to add a media query but I am not able to control the elements as I want. In specific (I am testing it with an Iphone5): the nav bar does not cover the full screen in the vertical view, the image is not centered, and the texts' margins are wrong... 
Here is an HTML example of the homepage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=content-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
  #logo {
    display: none;
  }

  div img {
    display: inline;
  }

  div footer-area {
    display: none;
  }

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    img {
      float: center;
  }

  div p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>

<img style="margin: -76px auto -55px auto; max-width: 450px;" src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/logo.png" alt="" width="1800" height="903" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-461" />
</head>
<body>
<div>[smartslider3 slider=4]</div>
<p style=" margin:70px 160px 0 160px;"><strong>Dottore Commercialista e Revisore Legale con sede a Verona</strong>, Alberto Nesso offre ai propri clienti una vasta gamma di prestazioni professionali di livello qualitativamente elevato entro un prezzo medio di mercato. L'attività di consulenza ordinaria contabile e fiscale, integrata all'occorrenza da servizi di assistenza amministrativa e aziendale-societaria, si rivolge ad imprese individuali, società di persone e capitali, enti no profit. Prestando attenzione alle esigenze di ciascun cliente, vengono fornite le informazioni specifiche, per massimizzare i risultati e le risoluzioni dei problemi, nella massima trasparenza e attraverso procedure giuridiche e fiscali coerenti con la strategia aziendale.</p>
<div style="margin: 30px 50px; " align="center"><a href="http://www.albertonesso.it/profilo/" target="_blank"><img style="padding-right: 10px; width: 240px;" src="http://www.albertonesso.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/HOME-profilo2.png" /></a><a href="http://www.albertonesso.it/competenze/" target="_blank"><img style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 5px; width: 240px;" src="http://www.albertonesso.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/HOME-competenze2.png" /></a><a href="http://www.albertonesso.it/contatti/"target="_blank"><img style="padding-left: 10px; width: 240px;" src="http://www.albertonesso.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/HOME-contatti2.png" /></a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the website address: https://www.albertonesso.it

Could you please help me in solving this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome, it looks like your problem on the homepage is that the nav is disappearing behind your share bar.  For me, in the browser, this code fixes it:

```
@media (max-width: 960px) {
   .site-navigation-inner {
      margin-top: 40px;
    }
}
```

You also have an unfortunate effect where some javascript is setting the margins on your content text so that it creates an excessively narrow column of text when viewed on a phone.

If possible, I would suggest that you remove that javascript and set the margins in css.  If it isn't possible for you to remove the js, you could override it with something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
   .entry-content p {
      margin: 0 40px !important;
    }
}
```

For the image, you could add:

```
   img.size-full {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

or, if this effects other images in undesireable ways:

```
   img.wp-image-461 {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

will only target the current logo image.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This nav bar problem is fixed also for me. Any suggestions for text and images?

Comment: Sure... Aside from the margins fix that I added, I don't really see any other problems.  How do you want the images to be different?

Also, I changed the width of the first media query.

Comment: Cool, thank you for the codes. There is the logo image which is not displaying properly, when the screen is vertical and smaller than 590px it goes over the screen in the right side... Do you see it from the mobile?

Comment: I tried both solutions for the images, in the home is working fine but I still see a clump of images in the other pages...

Comment: You can apply the same effect to other images by changing the css selector. replace "img.wp-image-461" with "img" or "article img" At this point this question is begining to evolve into "Please write all of my code for me." That's not what StackOverflow is about.

Comment: I din't mean this. sorry for pushing it

Comment: If the answer solved your problem you should accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: I can only accept it since I am new I don't have enough reputation points to vote nor to chat. I will do it when I will have the permission